# Aspect chain tracing in dspace 1.8.x

Tags: java, dspace, apache-cocoon

i would like to trace what aspect/transformer are involved in a request. Is there a way to do that in dspace 1.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the DRI page. You only need to add /DRI/ after /xmlui (or the name of the deployed webapp).

example: http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/DRI/password-login

Watching the ids you can see the java class that generate it.